# automatic summation on a text field with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Please help me , I would like to add three fields and results using jquery keyup and result in the total field , but did not want to work ?`

javascript

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function kerjakan() {
    var nilai1 = $('#input1').val();
    var nilai2 = $('#input2').val();
    var nilai3 = $('#input3').val();
    var nilai4 = parseInt(nilai1) + parseInt(nilai2) + parseInt(nilai3);

    if (nilai4 % 1 == 0) {
      $('#input4').val(nilai4);
    } else {
      $('#input4').val('');
    }
  }
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input1').keyup(kerjakan);
  $('#input2').keyup(kerjakan);
  $('#input3').keyup(kerjakan);
}); < /script>
```

```html
html
<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' onchange="kerjakan();" name="padi" id="input1" value=""></input>
  </td>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' onchange="kerjakan();" name="palawija" id="input2" value=""></input>
  </td>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' onchange="kerjakan();" name="tebu" id="input3" value=""></input>
  </td>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' name="total" id="input4" value=""></input>
  </td>
</div>
```

`

Comment: what did not work?what should happened?what is happening now?

Comment: total field would not automatically amount , what should I do with it now with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.input').on('input',function(){
var inputValues = $(".input").map(function() {
    return Number($(this).val());
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);
$('#input4').val(inputValues)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
html
<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' name="padi" id="input1" value="" class='input'></input>
  </td>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' name="palawija" id="input2" value="" class='input'></input>
  </td>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' name="tebu" id="input3" value="" class='input'></input>
  </td>
</div>

<div class='col-xs-1'>
  <td>
    <input type='text' size='5' id="input4" value="" ></input>
  </td>
</div>
```

Check this out